# Azure Event Grid Creating subscription : "Does not have authorization to perform action"

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I am currently using node js to publish topics to Event Grid, and subscribe to topics through Event Grid. Using the event grid API on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/ I get an error where I do not have authorization to perform action when creating a subscription. I have created a topic and have access permission to access my Azure account therefore I am confused why I get this rest error.

My code:

```
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { SystemTopicEventSubscriptions, EventGridManagementClientContext, DomainTopics, EventSubscriptions  } = require("@azure/arm-eventgrid");
const subscriptionId = "idea number";

const resourceGroupName = "eventgrid-dev";
const domainName = "test-domain";
let tenantId = "idea number";
let clientSecret = "idea number";
let clientId = "idea number";
const firstCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
//const client = new EventGridManagementClient(firstCredential, subscriptionId); 

const clientContext = new EventGridManagementClientContext(firstCredential, subscriptionId);

// Topics
let domainTopics = new DomainTopics(clientContext);

domainTopics.beginCreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, domainName, "test-topic")
.then(result => {
    console.log("result");
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(error);
}) 

let subscription = new EventSubscriptions(clientContext);
subscription.beginCreateOrUpdate("/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/eventgrid-dev", "test-subscription",{topic: "test-topic"})
.then(result => {
  console.log("result");
  console.log(result);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log("Error");
  console.log(error);
})
```

Output:

```
Error
RestError: The client 'subscriptionID' with object id 'subscriptionID' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/Microsoft.EventGrid/test-subscription/write' over scope '/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/eventgrid-dev/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please post your code as a text instead of using images, [why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of existing an event grid domain, use the following code for creating an event grid subscription on the requested topic. Note, that the topic is created automatically during its first subscription:

```
let subscription = new EventSubscriptions(clientContext);
const scope = '/subscriptions/' + subscriptionId + '/resourceGroups/' + resourceGroupName + '/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/' + domainName + '/topics/test-topic';
const test_webhookEndpointUrl = ' ... ';
subscription.beginCreateOrUpdate(scope, "test-subscription",
    {
        destination: {
            endpointType: "WebHook",
            endpointUrl: test_webhookEndpointUrl
        }      
    }
).then(result => {
        console.log("result");
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(error);
    })
```